# How EnB will inform to UE about incoming call in RRC connected state in LTE?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication, lte

Generally if `UE` is in `RRC Idle` state, `ENB` will inform to `UE` via **paging** message about CS domain i.e incoming call.

My doubt is in LTE, when `UE` is in `RRC Connected` State, how Network(EnB) will notify to `UE` about incoming `MT call` ? In which Information element(IE) or message ?

Any help will be appreciated !!